# WSO2 ESB adding a secure endpoint with custom certificate

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, wso2, wso2-esb

I need to configure a wso2 ESB proxy service to connect with a back end service which expose over HTTPS. To do this i need to insert and configure the SSL Certificate that i have with me.

Currently what i have done was include the certificate to wso2carbon.jks and client-truststore.jks in wso2esb-*\repository\resources\security folder and adding custom profile to axis2.xml in wso2esb-*\repository\conf\axis2 folder.

But when i try to test the URL when adding to wsdl based proxy it gives me following exception in console.

```
ERROR - ProxyServiceAdminClient Couldn't create endpoint from the given WSDL URI : java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found
org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.stub.ProxyServiceAdminProxyAdminException: Couldn't create endpoint from the given WSDL URI : java.security.cer
t.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this..?

Comment: Hi Sumedha i have tried with that, what finally fixed the issue was to avoid using IP addresses for CN and having same CN as the alias in keystore.

I have blogged about the solution http://sahanlm.tumblr.com/post/65311719934/wso2-esb-exposing-a-secure-backend-through-a-proxy.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting parameter "HostnameVerifier" in repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml as follows for HTTPS transport. More information on invoking a HTTPS endpoint can be found [here](http://blog.facilelogin.com/2011/02/wso2-esb-invoking-web-service-via-https.html).

```
<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>
```